# What does :wq stand for in Vim?

Tags: vim

Some of Vim's command names are obtuse to me and seem to have multiple aliases. It's easier for me to remember things if I know the reason they are used so...

What does `:wq` stand for, if anything? Where did `ZZ` (to do the same thing) come from? Is there a method to this madness?

Comment: Note that `ZZ` doesn't do exactly the same as `:wq`: the latter always saves before quitting, while the former only writes the file when there are unsaved changes.

Comment: `:wq` = "Write and quit".  `ZZ` = "Let's find a key combination that isn't used yet... Err, well..."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

:wq stands for: Write *and* Quit

Answer (score 0):

Anyone reading here who can't run the ":wq" for saving, read this: To save a file, you must first be in Command mode. Press Esc to enter Command mode, and then type ":wq" to write and quit the file.